# The same frame of the image, through the same algorithm or library, compression twice after the image is same or not

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, frame

The same frame of the image, through the same algorithm or library, lossy compression twice, compression twice after the image is same or not ?

Answer (score 2):

The image is not the same. Lossy encoders permanently manipulate the image to reduce file size while trying to make the quality appear good. This introduces artifacts which become part of the image that are not in the original. This is called generational loss.

JPG example:

1. Make JPG image:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i image.png image1.jpg
   ```
2. Re-encode:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i image1.jpg image2.jpg
   ```
3. Compare [hash](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#hash-1):

   ```
   ffmpeg -loglevel error -i image1.jpg -f hash -
   SHA256=9188931e7f40cd93101ef9eadaefa7ac8ace25c616e460fa7e58d8b4c7e138a1

   ffmpeg -loglevel error -i image2.jpg -f hash -
   SHA256=52c8b5ee9edbbc6e3a631d7f638df0d00a7c79ef10c7bb85659ff363a484be9d
   ```